# How do you stop this Jquery mousedown event from firing after the first event

Tags: jquery

I want to  fire an event when an image is clicked on but only once, IE disable the functionality after the first click. I tried..

```
var img = new Kinetic.Image({
                    x: position[rand][0],
                    y: position[rand][1],
                    image: imageObj,
                    width: 106,
                    height: 118
                });

img.on('mousedown', function(e) {

   do stuff

   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

and

```
img.on('mousedown', function() {

       do stuff

       return false;
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `one` instead of `on` to register the event just once.

```
img.one('mousedown', function(e) {

   do stuff

   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

You can also use `off` to turn off the event inside the `on` handler.

```
img.on('mousedown', function(e) {

   $(this).off('mousedown'); //turn off the handler
   do stuff

}
```

- [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)
- [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'one' (16:56:56:731 | error, javascript)
    at imageObj.onload (file)`

Comment: `<script src="scripts/kinetic-v4.3.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @DavidFolksman Also provide a JSFiddle to replicate the issue otherwise we can't help you just looking at the snippet you have posted in your question.

Comment: This is the best I could do, the event doesn't fire. :( it does in my local version.  You can see what im trying to do and that I want the event to only fire once. http://jsfiddle.net/9kyry/16/

Answer (score 1):

### Use modern Js event, with "once"!

```
img.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    // Do something
}, {once : true});
// You might also consider adding "capture : true" to replace stopPropogation
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once), [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)

Answer (score 0):

```
img.onclick = function() {
 do stuff
}
```

this will work :)

Comment: It fires more than once though

Comment: I know how to do events I just dont know how to turn them off, please read the question again.